# Running multiple vsftpd daemons with multiple PAM files

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, vsftpd, pam

If I am running multiple vsftpd daemons on a single machine, is it possible to specify the pluggable authentication module for each one?

In other words, can two vsftpd server instances run on different PAM files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `vsftpd.conf`, there's an option called `pam_service_name`. Looks like I can change that and create the proper files in `/etc`.